# Image loading in multithreading manner

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, image, memory-leaks

When I'm trying to load image's source in standalone thread that leads to memory leak (tons of HWNd pointers) (`ImgSource1` is bindable property at VM)

```
Thread task = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                ImageSource newSource = CreateImageSource(imageList[CurrentSourceIndex], true);
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    ImgSource1 = newSource; // <==  Memory leak is here
                });

                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                LogService.WriteLog(ex);
            }
            IsImageChangeAccessible = true;

        });
        task.IsBackground = true;
        task.Start();
```

If I'm using this code that lead to memory leak and wpf stop to draw images after ~20-30k loaded images. Memory leak based on Window pointer stored by Dispatcher. Here some images from memory profiler:
Call tree:
[image]
And memory diagram, leaked object at last spot of biggest objects diagram (`HwndSubclass`):
[image]

But when i'm using same code without `Thread` all work fine.... (didn't test thought in a long run test yet).

So how to load imagesource from file at multithreading maner without such memory leaks?

Image loading code:

```
var src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                src.Freeze();
                return src;
```

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: You haven't shown what's happening in `CreateImageSource` and what `imageList` is.

Comment: likely you are allocating some image resource that you should call dispose() on but aren't

Comment: @Sam .Net 4.6
@Clemens CreateImageSource() listed at the end of a post, and `imageList` is just a file names list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the possiblity to binding the `Source` property of  the `Image` control, and setting `IsAsync=True`, wpf will care about getting the image in a background thread by itself.

Generally speaking, wpf will keep controls in memory if they have a Name defined (or x:Name), so you should look out for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just tested it this night so far it works fine, will test in a long term.